# Carregar Images

Tags: javascript, jquery, load

Estou a ter um problema para carregar imagens de um ficheiro(pasta) para página web. Quando inicializa a página, apenas duas imagens são carregadas, as outras falham! Estou a usar JavaScript e Jquery, css/html.

```
var $galery = $('.galery');

function fetchArticles(contents){

    for(var i= 0 ; i <contents.length ; i ++){

        console.log(contents[i].images[0].id);

        $galery.append('<h2>'+contents[i].name+'</h2>');
        $galery.append('<p>'+contents[i].texto+'</p><br>');
        $galery.append('<p>'+contents[i].images[0].id+'</p><br>');
        var folder = "/static/img/ContentPhotos/";
        $galery.append('<img src='+folder+contents[i].images[0].name+' width="300" height="250"></img>');
    }
}
```

Comment: vendo apenas o código que vc disponibilizou, aparentemente está correto, vc está passando o nome dos arquivos corretamente? tente utilizar encodeURI(folder+contents[i].images[0].name) para ver se resolve

Comment: **Meu código:** `<img src="encodeURI('+folder+')" width="300" height="250" />` Resultado: <img src="encodeURI(/static/img/ContentPhotos/e2e000f4-7d75-4ef3-b825-a0d00c7cf535.jpg)" width="300" height="250" />

Comment: Com o meu código a página carrega as duas primeiras imagens, as restantes que começam sair quebradas!

Comment: E sim Vinicius, os nomes estão a ser passado corretamente. Tenho o receio como isto está a ocorrer em um loop de imagens que esta dentro de outro loop de conteúdos, e esteja dissincronizado!

Answer (score 0):

A propriedade `src` está sem aspas.
A tag `<img>` também não precisa de fechamento `</img>`

Segue o código corrigido:

`$galery.append("<img src='" + folder + contents[i].images[0].name + "' width='300' height='250'>");`

Comment: Caro Michel Lima, já testei de todas as maneiras.                              $galery.append('<img src="'+folder+'" width="300" height="250" />'); Só que o browser só carrega duas imagens e as demais a seguir ficam quebradas, como se não conseguisse carregar

Comment: Então coloca todo o html dentro de uma variável e depois usa o append.

`var html = "";
    for(var i= 0 ; i <contents.length ; i ++){
        html += '<h2>'+contents[i].name+'</h2>';
        html += '<p>'+contents[i].texto+'</p><br>';
        html += '<p>'+contents[i].images[0].id+'</p><br>';

        var folder = "/static/img/ContentPhotos/";

        html += "<img src='" + folder + contents[i].images[0].name + "' width='300' height='250'>";
        console.log(html);

    }
}
$galery.append(html);`

Verifica o que está sendo exibido no console do browser.